# Laravel redirect to external api and send data to api

Tags: laravel

I am trying to initiate a function when the user clicks on action, the function will redirect the page to the external domain page for verification of data and return a response from there back to the Laravel page,

```
   public function connect($id)
    {
        
        $data = Api::where('id', $id)->first();

        return redirect()->away('https://api.xxx.com/login/dialog')->with([ 
            'client_id' => $data->api_key, 
            'redirect_uri' => $data->redirect_uri,
            'response_type' => 'code'],
     );
    }
```

Now, the external page does not see this array of data, So the question is how can I pass data to the external page for API verification and back to the original redirect page for further processing?

Comment: and what kind of data format does the api accepts?

Comment: @OMiShah, it accept query parameters in URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel `redirect()->away()` can only make GET requests and not `POST` request. In order to attach the query parameters you can take the following approaches:

```
return redirect()->away('https://example.com?param1=value1');
```

OR

```
$param1 = 'value1';
$url = 'https://example.com?param1=' . urlencode($param1);
return redirect()->away($url);
```